# override and overload perspective

Tags: java

- Overloading  - same method with different signatures in the same
  class.
- Overriding - same method signature different implementations in
  subclass

If i have an overloaded method in the parent class does the child class overload or override this particular method?

Comment: No problem. In this case you will have a overriding (same signature from parent) and overload (different signature from parent)

Comment: Overriding.  Think that the child class is overriding the method since it won't be calling the parent method anymore.  For overloading think that you are getting overloaded with methods with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Overloading and overriding are not mutually exclusive.

```
class Parent {
    void foo() {}
    void foo(int a) {}
    void bar() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void foo() {} // overriding and overloading
    void foo(double b) {} // overloading
    void bar() {} // overriding
}
```

Comment: class Parent {
       
        void foo(int a) {}
     
    }
    
    class Child extends Parent {
       
        void foo( int a, double b) {} // is that overriding and overloading??
     
    }
    
    class Child extends Parent {
        void foo() {} // overriding and overloading
        void foo( int a, double b) {} // is that overriding and overloading??
        void bar() {} // overriding
    }

Answer (score 0):

Actually both because:

- Override - it has the same method signature as a method in the parent class.
- Overload - it has the same method name but a different signature as the parent class.